# Swift: Can't synchronize data to table view using Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, asynchronous, firebase

I was working on a grocery list app. When I tried to synchronise data to table view using Firebase, the grocery item can not be shown on the table view. However, when I reset the simulator, items added before can be shown on the table view, but when I add another item, it can't be shown on the table view. I double checked the code and found nothing wrong. Could you help me fix it?(e.g. In the following two images, the coffee item can not be shown)

**Part of code in GroceryListViewController.swift**

```
 override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
super.viewDidAppear(animated)
//Attach a listener to receive updates.
ref.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in

    var newItems = [GroceryItem]()

    for item in snapshot.children
    {
        let groceryItem = GroceryItem(snapshot: item as! FDataSnapshot)
        newItems.append(groceryItem)
    }
    self.items = newItems
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    })
}
```

[image: Simulator Image]
[image: Firebase Image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - You are using observeSingleEventOfType (* This is equivalent to observeEventType:withBlock:, except the block is immediately canceled after the initial data is returned.) From the doc. So your listener is called once and stop listening. Use observeEventType instead

2 - You should do the reloadData of your tableview on the main thread like this :

```
 NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock({
      self.tableView.reloadData()
 })
```

The reason is that you cannot / must not interact with UI from a background thread. Since Firebase is asynchronous the completion block is on a background thread

Comment: I have added this code, but it didn't work. The tableView remained the same.

Comment: Ok, I just realised you were using observeSingleEventOfType. Try using observeEventType(FEventType.ChildChanged, ....

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's obvious, but it happen to me. I was debugging and the code was stopped in a breakpoint, and data was not in the console in firebase. Then I realized that I had to let it run completely to refresh. Maybe it can help...

Answer (score 0):

Add this code once touch the button "+":

```
 self.items.append(groceryItem)
  let row = self.items.count - 1
  let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: row, inSection: 0)
  self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
```

This ensures the interaction with  UI.